# Is there a way to create shorcut that move an app on specific workspace AND specific screen

Tags: gnome, shortcut-keys, multiple-monitors, workspaces

As many I'm using 2 screens on my desk. I have one laptop with its screen and an additional monitor.

I'm using 4 workspaces.
Workspaces are used only on the main screen (the big one, not the laptop's one), they are not extended on the laptop.
On the laptop I'm using slack.
On the main/big monitor I'm using everything else.

Sometimes, laptop connection(usb-c) fail on startup and I need to unplug/plug the usb hub to get all connected. When this happens, all my app opened at startup, are on my laptop screen and I need to move all of them one the main screen.

**Is there a way to create a shortcut to move the active app on main screen AND workspace X ?**
Have a nice day.